# Determine whether a romanized name is Japanese or not, preferably in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nlp, cjk

How can I determine whether a romanized name is likely, or unlikely, to be a Japanese name?

```
"Yukihiro Matsumoto".likely_to_be_japanese? # => true
"John Smith".likely_to_be_japanese? # => false
```

Ideally, I'd also like to feed in free-form text, and detect whether the text has a name likely to be Japanese, has a name unlikely to be Japanese, or doesn't have any names in it. Preferably ignoring false positives.

```
"call Koichi on (02) 5550 5555".has_japanese_name_in_it? # => true
"call John on (02) 5550 5556".has_non_japanese_name_in_it? # => true
"utility bill to be shared equally".has_non_japanese_name_in_it? => false
```

Are there any libraries that can help me do this, preferably in Ruby? Or would I have to find a corpus of Japanese, and non-Japanese, names and build my own solution?

Comment: you'll find [lists of japanese surnames](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Japanese_surnames#A) on the web, you could match against that but it'll never be totally perfect. `"utility bill to be shared equally".has_non_japanese_name_in_it? => false` would even need to be context aware unless you'll require Capitals for names: Bill vs bill

Comment: With language, I think you can detect pragmatically what language some text is pretty easily. Names, however, I don't think can be easily pragmatically recognized without a list of common names and spellings to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like google translate. Translating matsumoto from english to japanese will give you a 2 kanji result (matsu + moto) because it's japanese.

Comment: That gives Kanji for many Korean and Chinese names, too: http://translate.google.com/#en|ja|matsumoto%20yukihiro%0Awen%20jiabao%0Akim%20jong%20il%0A

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a surname which translates to a 2 kanji result will generally be japanese.

Comment: That is probably true in surprisingly many cases, but there are still 1-Kanji (and 3-Kanji) Japanese surnames. Anyway, it's certainly an original approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get real fancy, hook in to the Stanford Parser with [this](http://stanfordparser.rubyforge.org/) and hack apart your sentences and the names.

You're looking for NNPs, so your output looks like this

```
Parsing [sent. 1 len. 5]: Matsumoto was a nice guy
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Matsumoto))
    (VP (VBD was)
      (NP (DT a) (JJ nice) (NN guy)))))
```

Then you'd be using some dictionary lookup for the Japanese part

Really, though, you'd probably do just fine splitting the string and doing the dictionary lookup yourself.

Comment: Good idea. Once you have found the noun phrases you can use the list of Japanese names (in one of the comments) to train a supervised classifier to recognise Japanese-looking words. Useful features might include what the suffix of the word is and what characters combinations it contains (I do not speak any Japanese so can't think of anything else). I suggest looking at the [language identification][1] literature for feature ideas.